# how to compare array element in assesmbly?

Tags: assembly, arm

I'm new to assembly language and I'm trying to do a binary search tree with the following code, however the logic at the bold parts don't seem to be correct...any fix?

- how to compare array elements?
- how to compare the elements within an array while using loops?
- is my logic correct?

````
        AREA bsttest, CODE, READONLY
        ENTRY
        
Reset_Handler

    ADR r0,Arr ;r0 pointer to arr (array)
    ADR r1,smallest ;r1 pointer to smallest (array)
    ADR r2,greatest ;r2 pointer to greatest (array)
    
    MOV r3,#5 ;5 is the size of array
loop    
    LDRB r5,[r0],#1; load the first element into r5 and set this as root
    **LDRB r6,[r0,#1]** ; load the second element into r6 using pre-increment 
    
    
    CMP r6,r5 ; compare r6 and r5
    BGE storeatright ; if r6 is greater than r5 jump to the label
    
    ;if r6<r5
    **CMP r1,#0**; check if there's a value on the left hand side, if LHS=NULL,
    BGT jump; if it's not NULL, jump
    STRB r6,[r1],#1 ;save and store value at the LHS
jump
    STRB r5,[r1],#1 ;save and store value at the LHS
    
    ;if r6>r5
storeatright 
    
    **CMP r2,#0**; check if there's a value on the right hand side, if RHS=NULL,
    BGT jumps; if it's not NULL, jump
    STRB r6,[r2],#1 ;save and store value at the RHS
jumps
    STRB r5,[r2],#1 ;save and store value at the RHS
    SUBS r3,r3,#1 ; i-- for array
    BNE loop ; loop until array size=0

        
Arr DCB 2,1,4,3,5;array
smallest DCB 0,0,0,0,0 
greatest DCB 0,0,0,0,0

stop    B stop
        END```
````

Answer (score 1):

The first load, `ldrb r5,[r0],#1`, loads the first byte (from the initial `r0`), and then increments the pointer, so `r0` now points to the 2nd byte of the array (i.e. at index 1).

The second load, `ldrb r6,[r0,#1]`, loads the third byte, because (1) the pointer has been already incremented, and (2) a displacement addressing mode is used with offset=1, so from pointer referring to index 1, adding 1 makes it refer to index 2, which is the third element.

---

As far as the compare for null, these are good to check but either your logic is bad or the terminology is incorrect..

```
CMP r1,#0**; check if there's a value on the left hand side, if LHS=NULL,
BGT jump; if it's not NULL, jump
STRB r6,[r1],#1 ;save and store value at the LHS
```

We wouldn't use BGT to check for NULL, we would instead use BNE there.  So, either the code is checking for >0 integer and the comments are wrong, or the code is incorrectly checking for a NULL pointer.

If the comments are correct that the intent is about checking for NULL, however, the code then goes on to write to memory using that NULL pointer, which would be bad.

---

I don't see trees involved here — just a few arrays.  Because of that, I would say that the NULL checking is erroneous, and should be removed — just store into the array.  Since you're advancing the pointer after store, its ready for the next store without further checking.

---

I suggest that you start with a C version of this.  Do all your pointer optimizations in the C version, making sure it actually works.  Then translate your pointer-optimized, working C version to assembly being fairly literal.

Don't start with an array version in C and then try to optimize pointers as you're translating to assembly, unless you want frustration.

Comment: Hi Erik, do u think you would you be able to show me a quick example on how to do that? I do know the concept of binary search tree but I really have no clue on how to implement that in assembly language, I've only learnt the basics of it and my C isn't strong, I'm a really new to this field

Comment: Separate the concepts of algorithm from assembly language.  Algorithms are language independent, often written in pseudo code, and C also very common.  So, search for tree code in C or pseudo code and leave the assembly translation for when you understand the algorithm.

Comment: What we should want to learn about assembly is how we do high level language constructs in assembly, rather than how to develop algorithms from scratch in assembly.  So, constructs like functions, arrays & array references, pointer arithmetic, if-then/else, for/while loops, etc.

Comment: If you work out designs on paper even before you start to write a program or choose a programming language, now you're starting to think like a programmer.  Knowing what you want to a program to accomplish is a harder problem than assembly language, so don't make yourself think in assembly language about designs & algorithms.

Comment: I see, my approach was I studied the algorithm first and translated the pseudocode into assembly(like the code above) but I'm stuck at here and there

Comment: Is the logic above entirely wrong? Or is there anything that I can improve on?

Comment: Can you reference or share the pseudo code?  This assembly code doesn't have any trees in it, so, hard for us to say what it is supposed to do, and, knowing that is necessary to answer about the logic being right.

Comment: ```Struct BST
{
     int value;
     struct BST*left;
     struct BST*right;
}
*p, *q, *root;

root-> value a[0]
for i->1 to n
{
      q-> value=a[i];
      p=root;

While(1)
{
     if (q-> value <= p->value)
{
if (p-> left == NULL)
     p-> left =q;
else
     p=p-> left;
}
else if(q-> value>p-> value)
{
if (p-> right == NULL)
     p-> right =q;
else
     p=p-> right;
}
}```

Comment: This is the pseudocode that I'm trying to convert